# Some installed packages not found

Tags: packages, editors, textmate

I'm using LaTeX on a Mac. The editor I use is [Textmate 2](http://macromates.com/).

When I hit "typeset & view", what I get is something like

> `! LaTeX Error: File 'xy.sty' not found.`

However, if I do `pdflatex abc.tex` from the command line, everything works fine.

From the information provided by pdfLaTeX, I noticed that the only `.sty` files that can be found are in the folder
`/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/`, while the other packages are in places like `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/`.

That seems to cause the problem. I don't want to shuffle `.sty` files among folders. Can I make things work by changing some settings? Like can I let the compiler know to look for some `.sty` files in some other folders under `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/`?

Comment: Did you install MacTeX from Safari? I have a friend who had problems when he used Chrome  to download it on his Mac.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with browser. It is more about settings.

Comment: Try compiling `abc.tex` first from the Terminal and then from TextMate; for both cases, add here the 20 lines of the log file.

Comment: @egreg I solved the problem. See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. It's more about installing TeX Live on a Mac than about TextMate 2.

This problem is likely to be caused by installing Tex Live twice. Here is the solution:

1. Clean out all previous Tex Live file. (`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive`)
2. On Mac OS X, an online installation is done by a command line tool (`install-tl`) with a text interface. Make sure it is a "sudo install" (on a Mac, the installer need root privilege but won't have it if not "sudo"ed.) Put type `sudo` and then drag the `install-tl` Unix executable in the terminal. Put in password if necessary.
3. Be sure to set the options (O) before installing, tick the box of `create symlinks in standard directories:`(L) (This is why you need a sudo install.)
4. After installation, tick the box of `PATH` in `> Preference > Variables` of TextMate. Make sure the directory of `kpsewhich` (which you can find by putting `which kpsewhich` in the terminal) is in the `PATH` variable.